# What is the MSBuild Property that specifies where the code is being placed on the build server?

Tags: msbuild

I am compressing CSS and JS files to a single file respectively these files get created but then we have a build folder that has everything in the fold but the min CSS and JS.

My idea is to just setup a copy command and get the files over to where they need to be .....

Ex ..

> \usbpx2kfsptfs02.kfs.local\d$\TfsPublish\MYPROJECT\_PublishedWebsites

What is the MSBuild Property that specifies where the code is being placed on the build server ?

I would like to copy some files from $(OutDir) to where everything is packaged up but I don't know the property for that

Comment: Need more detail. What do you mean, "packaged up"? Why don't the files get copied already? In many cases, you just have to set things up, and they get moved to the right places.

Comment: Are you using Web Deploy (MSDEPLOY)?

Comment: No I am using MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks but I could switch I guess

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DropLocation`:

> $(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Release_PublishedWebsites\

Comment: $(DropLocation) does not return anything .. nor does $(BuildNumber)

Comment: I found `DropLocation` by queuing a build with the verbosity set to "Diagnostic", then looking at the log. I just looked at such a log and saw that `DropLocation` is set at the beginning of the build to the parameter value in the "Build Defaults" tab of the build process definition. Later, the "UpdateBuildNumberDropLocation" task is run, and adds the build number to the `DropLocation` property.